# Cloud Formation: separate cloudformation template of S3 bucket and Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have created a cloudformation template to configure a S3 bucket with an event notification that will call a lambda function. The lamba is triggered whenever a new object is created in the bucket. 
The problem I have is when I delete the stack the bucket is also deleted. For debugging and testing purpose I had to delete the stack.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Upload an object to an S3 bucket, triggering a Lambda event, returning the object key as a Stack Output.
Parameters:
  Body:
    Description: Stack to create s3 bucket and the lambda trigger
    Type: String
    Default: Test
  BucketName:
    Description: S3 Bucket name
    Type: String
    Default: image-process-bucket

Resources:
  ImageProcessorExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal: 
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: S3Policy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - 's3:PutObject'
            - 'S3:DeleteObject'
            Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}/*"

  ImageProcessor:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: Prints the filename
      Handler: imageProcessor.handler
      Role: !GetAtt ImageProcessorExecutionRole.Arn
      Code: .
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Environment:
        Variables:
          BucketName:
            Ref: BucketName

  Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DependsOn: BucketPermission
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref BucketName
      NotificationConfiguration:
        LambdaConfigurations:
        - Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
          Function: !GetAtt ImageProcessor.Arn

  BucketPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: !Ref ImageProcessor
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceAccount: !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}"
```

To resolve this, I separated the two resources on separate template using Outputs. Problem with this is that I cannot delete Lambda function stack because it is being referenced by the Bucket stack.

1. I want to know what is the right approach. Is it really required to separate these two resources. I believe lambda function is required to be changed frequently.
2. If yes what is the correct way to do it.
3. If not how should I handle the necessity to makes changes.
4. The approach using Outputs and Imports will always create the dependencies and will not allow to delete. This is a generic behavior in any resources. How do we deal with deleting in this case.Is it good to use this approach

```
Description: Upload an object to an S3 bucket, triggering a Lambda event, returning the object key as a Stack Output.
Parameters:
 Body:
   Description: Stack to create s3 bucket and the lambda trigger
   Type: String
   Default: Test
 BucketName:
   Description: S3 Bucket name
   Type: String
   Default: image-process-bucket

Resources:
 ImageProcessorExecutionRole:
   Type: AWS::IAM::Role
   Properties:
     AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
       Version: '2012-10-17'
       Statement:
       - Effect: Allow
         Principal: 
           Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
         Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
     Path: /
     ManagedPolicyArns:
     - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
     Policies:
     - PolicyName: S3Policy
       PolicyDocument:
         Version: '2012-10-17'
         Statement:
         - Effect: Allow
           Action:
           - 's3:PutObject'
           - 'S3:DeleteObject'
           Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}/*"

 ImageProcessor:
   Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
   Properties:
     Description: Prints the filename
     Handler: imageProcessor.handler
     Role: !GetAtt ImageProcessorExecutionRole.Arn
     Code: .
     Runtime: nodejs12.x
     Environment:
       Variables:
         BucketName:
           Ref: BucketName
Outputs:
 ImageProcessingARN:
   Description: ARN of the function
   Value: 
     Fn::Sub: ${ImageProcessor.Arn}
   Export:
     Name: ImageProcessingARN
 ImageProcessingName:
   Description: Name of the function
   Value: !Ref ImageProcessor
   Export:
     Name: ImageProcessingName
```

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Test
Parameters:
  BucketName:
    Description: Name of the bucket
    Type: String
    Default: imageprocess-bucket

Resources:
  Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DependsOn: BucketPermission
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref BucketName
      NotificationConfiguration:
        LambdaConfigurations:
        - Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
          Function: 
            Fn::ImportValue: ImageProcessingARN

  BucketPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: 
        Fn::ImportValue:  ImageProcessingName
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceAccount: !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}"
```

Comment: Hadronymous answer below will help you.  But, I want to ask, why are deleting the Function stack instead of updating it?  If you use Retain as Hadronymous suggests, you could put both back into one stack and delete the whole stack, while retaining the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no such thing as the right approach, it almost always depends on your unique situation. Strictly speaking it is not required to separate the resources in different CloudFormation templates. A lambda function that changes a lot is also not a sufficient reason for separating the resources.
2. You seem to be separating the resources correctly in two different stacks. You just do not like that you have to delete the S3 bucket first because it makes debugging more difficult.
3. If my assumption is correct that you want to delete or update the Lambda CloudFormation stack frequently while not wanting to delete S3 bucket, then there are at least 2 solutions to this problem:

   - Put a [Deletion Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) and an [UpdateReplacePolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatereplacepolicy.html) on your S3 bucket. By adding these policies you can delete the CloudFormation stack, while keeping the S3 bucket. This will allow you to keep the S3 bucket and the Lambda function in one CloudFormation Template. To create the new stack again, remove the S3 Bucket Resource from the template and [manually import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html) the resource back into the CloudFormation stack later.
   - Use [Queue Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig-queueconfig.html) as [Notification Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig.html). This is a good approach if you plan on separating the CloudFormation Template in a S3 bucket template and a Lambda function template (a decision based on frequency of change and dependencies between the two templates). Put an [SQS queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sqs-queues.html) in the S3 bucket template. Create the CloudFormation stack based on the S3 bucket template. Use the SQS arn (as a CloudFormation template configuration parameter or use the ImportValue intrinsic function) in the Lambda function stack and let [SQS trigger the Lambda function](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-adds-amazon-simple-queue-service-to-supported-event-sources/). I think this is the best approach since you can now remove the Lambda function stack without having to delete the S3 bucket stack. This way you effectively reduce the coupling between the two CloudFormation stacks since you make the SQS in the S3 bucket stack unaware of potential Lambda function listeners.

   4: I think that it is still possible to delete the S3 bucket CloudFormation stack first and delete the Image Processing Lambda CloudFormation stack second. Although I assume this is not something you typically want to do.